# Mapping Knockout.js Observable Array with different ViewModels

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I got the following sample response from server ( The original will be much more nested )

```
{
   Widgets: [
       { type: 'Multivalue',value: ['val1','val2','val3'] },
       { type: 'OtherType',value: 'val', otherProp: 'prop' }
       { type: 'Text',value: 'text here' }
   ]
}
```

I know what are the available widget types so I have ViewModels for each widget as above:

```
   var MultiValueVM = function(){
     // some props
     this.values = ko.observableArray()
   }

    var OtherValueVM = function(){
     // some props
   }

   var TextValueVM = function(){
     // some props
   }

   //More ViewModels for all types of widgets..
```

And my main ViewModel

```
   var MainVM = function(){
      //some props
      this.widgets = ko.observableArray();
   }
```

I'm in big confusion how to map the Collection of different objects from the server to my MainVM.widgets so that each widgets has its own ViewModel..

Comment: What do you currently have to map them? Can you include your code, tell us what the specific problem is with your current implementation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeroen, I already found a way to map the data I added a ViewModel Factory and when json data comes to the MainVM.widgets depending on the coming widget type i yeld the corresponding VM's from factory to be populated

Comment: Yes, I understood as much. Can you edit your question and include the relevant code? It may be *there* where your solution lies. It would be best if you'd create a working example scenario which we can toy with.